# Efficient way of importing data from Excel Sheets, row by row, to be handed over to various tables in SQL Database end

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a requirement to pull in thousands of records from an excel sheet into SQL. I have a Windows Client front end built that allows the user to select the Excel file(templated) to upload and then handle the data row by row. I tried using SSIS but since I am brand new to that, I am not having much luck there. Wanted to know if I can using plain old C# code efficiently the same import, and do so in best time?

Comment: You can use plain old c# code from within SSIS using the script task.

Comment: Is that option really more efficient approach?

Comment: **Most efficient** is probably going to be using tools that you're familiar with. I just wanted to point out that you can use c# from within SSIS. You should probably try **something** and then post your results. Lots of people can help if you run into an actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hint, to point you in a promising direction, I'll suggest you work with array-copies of your excel-data. You can even  copy those to memory / generate pointers to them, which might increase your performance.

Comment: no -pointers in excel through dll-calls - but i think this might not be right here ...